# What is the differences between MS DOS & Powershell in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, ms-dos

What makes them differ from each other?  I was just experimenting with MS DOS, and then found Powershell. Can't figure out why Microsoft gave them.

Comment: You do mean command prompt, right? With the cmd shell?  Dos has been dead for quite a while as far as windows goes. Its an *ex* os.

Comment: Yeah, i was just experimenting with it.  Since we have that in our syllabus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, powershell is fully fledged, extensible scripting platform whereas ms-dos isn't. ms-dos was fine for Windows 98 but not anymore. Microsoft is heavily investing in powershell development. They are trying to present powershell like what BASH is to Linux. In newer OS from Microsoft, you can nearly do all tasks using powershell commandlets. What you can do in Dos can also be done in powershell but reverse is not true. There are a great number of third party commandlets available for powershell which makes it very flexible.

Comment: Gonna Use Powershell from now onwards. : )

Comment: PowerShell is a full programming language with complete .NET integration. In theory we could rewrite every program on Windows in PowerShell. The same is definitely not true of CMD.EXE batch.

Comment: Please stop telling people that Windows has DOS. It's called **command prompt** and it's not DOS. The last Windows that had DOS components was Windows Me.